# Is it possible to run scripts defined in package.json from outside of package.json's directory?

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, package.json

I'd like to replicate webpack's ability to be run from any directory with npm scripts.

For example this works with Webpack

`webpack --config /absolute/path/to/webpack.config.js`

Is there an equivalent for npm scripts, e.g.

`/absolute/path/to/package.json/npm run build`?

I'm trying to avoid having to `cd` in, run the script, then `cd` out again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not seem to be any option in npm to specify a folder, so I think you will have to cd into the directory, run your npm command, then cd out again (note that $OLDPWD automatically holds the previous working directory - you don't have to assign it):

```
cd /path/to/package.json; npm run build; cd $OLDPWD
```

However, if an error occurs during your npm call, you will be stuck in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--prefix` in an npm command to specify the directory of the npm package you want to run the command with. For your example, that would look like:

```
npm run build --prefix /absolute/path/to
```